# Laravel MySQL to SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, laravel

We have developed project in Laravel with Mysql want to connect the project to SQL Server database. The project is not able to connect to SQL Server - we're getting the following error:

> SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]
>   [SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. (SQL: select sum([credit]) as aggregate from [loan_transactions] where [transaction_type] = repayment and [reversed] = 0 and [date] between date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and now())
>   (View: D:\Xampp\htdocs\loanmanager\resources\views\dashboard.blade.php)

Comment: Does the table [users] exist in your schema?

Comment: yes now i am getting the following error SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. (SQL: select sum([credit]) as aggregate from [loan_transactions] where [transaction_type] = repayment and [reversed] = 0 and [date] between date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and now()) (View: D:\Xampp\htdocs\loanmanager\resources\views\dashboard.blade.php)

Comment: Edit your question and add the error and the query that's generating the error

Comment: it looks like you've connected to the database and it has tried to run an SQL statement - my best guess is that the SELECT statement isn't compatible with SQL Server, things like date_sub or now() (I'm used to using getdate() instead) may not be recognised SQL Server commands.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to run a query with MySQL specific syntax that is not compatible with MSSql. Instead of using the `date_sub()` MySQL function, try using the MSSql equivalent:

```
... and [date] between DATEADD(week, -1, GETDATE()) and GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just can't comment. Migrations can be a fuzz as well when it comes to supporting both MySQL and MSSQL, not just with FK and indexes but a lot of stuff. Just a tip, if you're using an if-statement to support both, this can be one way `env('DB_CONNECTION') === 'sqlsrv'`